# How can I assign a numerical value to cell that contains text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I am trying to assign numerical values to a list of drop down values that are able to be selected via list data validation. I want to display the text, however be able to quantify my results with the corresponding numerical value.

e.g

[image: Excel example]

**Business Value**

Small

Medium

Large

**Values**

1

2

3

Comment: There are several ways to do this (`IF`, `INDEX/MATCH`, `VLOOKUP`...) A bit more context and knowing what you tried and how it failed ot achieve the desired result may help us provide a better answer.

Comment: Better you go with dependent Drop down method .

Comment: Sure. For example when I select 'Small' for business value, I want that to be captured as a 1 (integer) so that I can quantify my results in a formula.

Comment: THANK YOU! I figured it out with Match.

Answer (score 0):

Lookups are arguably the most practical method but it sounds like you want to use Custom Number Formats because that is precisely what they do.  There's a limit to the number of values you can assign this way so they may not be suitable for you.  If you only have three values then it's a no brainier.  This is one of the better write ups I've been able to find on them:  https://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-custom-number-formats-excel/

And if you want get creative, you can explore off the wall options like using a second line in a cell or creating a formula to convert your string to the desired value.

Really, your imagination is the only limit once you get your geek on..

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out.